# Read / Write data from HBase using Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data from HBase using Pyspark and it is getting many weird errors. Below is the sample snippet of my code.

Please suggest any solution.

```
empdata = ''.join("""
    {
        'table': {
            'namespace': 'default',
            'name': 'emp'
        },
        'rowkey': 'key',
        'columns': {
            'emp_id': {'cf': 'rowkey', 'col': 'key', 'type': 'string'},
            'emp_name': {'cf': 'personal data', 'col': 'name', 'type': 'string'}
        }
    }
""".split())

df = sqlContext \
    .read \
    .options(catalog=empdata) \
    .format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase') \
    .load()

df.show()
```

I have used the below version

**HBase 2.1.6,
Pyspark 2.3.2, Hadoop 3.1**

I have ran the code as follows

```
pyspark --master local --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-1.6-s_2.10 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
```

The error is

```
An error occurred while calling o71.load. : java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: org/apache/apark/Logging
```

Comment: what error did you get???

Comment: @mck i have updated the error as well